# How to to use a cgi file without an extension as index in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi

I'm using WebMin to administer an Apache server and am having trouble getting Apache to use a python CGI file without an extension (named "home") as my index.

The file is executable and works OK if I type the URL like this:
http://example.com/home

but I want this to get there too:
http://example.com

Instead, I get a permission denied error.

I have "home" set as my index file and access control set to allow all for that directory. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the following directives to your configuration:

```
<File home>
  SetHandler cgi-script
  Options +ExecCGI
</File>
```

These could go in .htaccess or inside e.g. `<Location /> ... </Location>`.